# Nextjs displays white screen during development

Tags: next.js

When I run `yarn dev` I get the following error

> (node:171412) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot set
> property 'status' of undefined at
> xxx\my-next-app\node_modules\next\dist\server\hot-reloader.js:16:94 at
> async Promise.all (index 0) at async DynamicEntryPlugin.config.entry
> (xxx\my-next-app\node_modules\next\dist\server\hot-reloader.js:15:96)
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was
> created) (node:171412) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of
> an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise
> which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on
> unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag
> `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 32)

I have been unable to figure out the issue

My next version is ^10.0.4

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope @AliBaghban. I had to undo all the settings that led to this situation.